# Add awesome font icon to menu item

Tags: theming, 8, navigation

In my menu I want to add icons. Now when I look for a way to do this, I found a module called [Menu Link Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_link_attributes). When I configure this on all my menu items, I can't only get it working when using the link function in twig. Now this is not a the expected way of working. Because in the module I add the class names of a awesome font icon. So I need to find a way to manually place the class in my twig file.

The module settings looks like:

```
attributes:
  class:
    label: ''
    description: ''
```

I treid using the {{ item.attributes }} in my menu.html.twig file but this is always empty.

Can someone help me on this? How can I place the class attribute in a custom i tag?

Comment: Did you figure this out? Trying to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a module available specifically for this use case, namely using Font Awesome icons as menu items: https://www.drupal.org/project/fontawesome_menu_icons